# exePath is invalid exception in ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration

Tags: c#

I have a windows service which is installed to C:\Windows\System32. It has a usual .config file, where some app settings are stored. I have another app that writes some values to this config. When i run this app it throws an exception at this line

`var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(serviceExePath);`

The exception says: *An error occurred loading a configuration file: The parameter 'exePath' is invalid. Parameter name: exePath*

When I put my windows service to another folder everything is ok! Is it due to some access violation rules or smth like that? Is there any way to use System32 folder for my service and open its config?

OS: Windows 7 x64

Comment: can you explain why you're putting it in system32?  Normally you'd put it into a Program Files subdir or the like, so explaining the goal of using System32 may help in getting a recommendation for a better location

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a poor choice for a file location.  That directory belongs to Windows, it isn't suitable for your own apps.  For one, you'll need admin privileges to open files in that directory.  You don't get that without a manifest to trigger the UAC prompt.

For another, that directory is virtualized on the x64 version of Windows.  A 32-bit app trying to access files there will be redirected to c:\windows\syswow64.

I could have been more accurate if you posted the stack trace.  But, just don't do it.

Answer (score 7):

Note that despite the name of the parameter being 'exePath', you should be passing in the name of the .config file, so you might need to append '.config' based on what's in your serviceExePath folder.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224437.aspx

> exePath
>
> Type: System.String
>
> The path of the configuration file. The configuration file resides in the same directory as the executable file.

As it stands, I get the feeling it's trying to load the actual .exe as a config file, which certainly explains why it considers it to be invalid :)

Comment: From .NET 3.5 and up, the comment for `exePath` in the link you provided is "The path of the executable (exe) file." I guess they made it smart enough to find the .config file from that.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try, it has helped me in the past:
http://sandblogaspnet.blogspot.com/2009/06/reading-from-configuration-file-in-net.html