# Cannot initialize public static class when the DLL is placed in a remote server

Tags: c#, dll, static

This question derives another question ["DLL cannot find AppConfig file on remote location"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19097188/dll-cannot-find-appconfig-file-on-remote-location) As at first I wasn't able to get detail stack trace on Powershell, but later when I find out a way to see the stack trace, I realize the question may not be accurate and may be a new question.

I have a DLL in a network shared folder, and after I import it to PowerShell by using `Import-Module`, calling the DLL's methods shows this error:

> The type initializer for Configuration.AppConfiguration threw an exception

and the exception is a `TypeInitializationException`.

The exception is thrown for the class:

```
namespace Configuration
public static class AppConfiguration
{
    private static Configuration Configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(new Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase).AbsolutePath);
    public static string name {...}
    public static int timeout {...}
}
```

If I copy the DLL to my local folder, the error will not happen and everything works correctly, however on that remote location, it just doesn't work.

Comment: And what exactly does the TypeInitializationException say? You should *never* ask a question stating that there's been an error without giving all the details of that error.

Comment: @JonSkeet more detail is given in the link I provided after the edit.thanks!

Comment: Sounds to me like you only have one real question, so you should only *ask* one real question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you class does not have the default constructor , add a default static/non static constructor to class that is throwing this error

Comment: The exception detail seems like another issue though:
System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: An error occurred loading a configuration file: The parameter 'exePath' is invalid. Parameter name: exePath ---> System.ArgumentException: The parameter 'exePath' is invalid.

Comment: then try this answer here I think the location of your config file is not the same as exe file 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3283051/exepath-is-invalid-exception-in-configurationmanager-openexeconfiguration