# DLL cannot find AppConfig file on remote location

Tags: c#, dll

This question is derive from ["Cannot initialize public static class when the DLL is placed in a remote server"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19056048/cannot-initialize-public-static-class-when-the-dll-is-placed-in-a-remote-server) As at first I wasn't able to get detail stack trace on Powershell, but later when I find out a way to do it, I realize the question may not be accurate and may be a new question.

I have a DLL in a network shared folder, and after I import it to PowerShell by using `Import-Module`, calling the DLL's methods shows this error:

> The type initializer for Configuration.AppConfiguration threw an exception
>
> TypeName       : InsightDSL.DSLConfiguration.AppConfiguration
>
> Message        : The type initializer for 'InsightDSL.DSLConfiguration.AppConfiguration' threw an exception.
>
> Data           : {}
>
> InnerException : System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: An error occurred loading a configuration file: The parameter 'exePath' is invalid.
>                    Parameter name: exePath ---> System.ArgumentException: The parameter 'exePath' is invalid.
>                    Parameter name: exePath
>                       at System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths..ctor(String exePath, Boolean includeUserConfig)
>                       at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationHost.get_ConfigPaths()
>                       at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationHost.GetStreamName(String configPath)
>                       at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.InitConfigFromFile()
>                       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>                       at System.Configuration.ConfigurationSchemaErrors.ThrowIfErrors(Boolean ignoreLocal)
>                       at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfParseErrors(ConfigurationSchemaErrors schemaErrors)
>                       at System.Configuration.Configuration..ctor(String locationSubPath, Type typeConfigHost, Object[] hostInitConfigurationParams)
>                       at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationHost.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationFileMap fileMap, Boolean isMachine,
>                    ConfigurationUserLevel userLevel, String exePath)
>                       at InsightDSL.DSLConfiguration.AppConfiguration..cctor()
>
> TargetSite     : Int32 get_TimeoutValue()
>
> StackTrace     :    at InsightDSL.DSLConfiguration.AppConfiguration.get_TimeoutValue()
>                       at InsightDSL.SetInsightConnection.SetEnvironment()
>                       at InsightDSL.SetInsightConnection.ProcessRecord()
>                       at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.ProcessRecord()

The exception is thrown for the class:

```
namespace Configuration
public static class AppConfiguration
{
    private static Configuration Configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(new Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase).AbsolutePath);
    public static string name {...}
    public static int timeout {...}
}
```

If I copy the DLL to my local folder, the error will not happen and everything works correctly, however on that remote location, it just doesn't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot initialize public static class when the DLL is placed in a remote server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19056048/cannot-initialize-public-static-class-when-the-dll-is-placed-in-a-remote-server)

Comment: @DaveZiegler that was my question too, but I realized the question seems not accurate so I ask a new one.